# Threesum problem using python unable to satisfy all the cases

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve the famous `[Threesum][1]` problem with the help of `dictionaries`. The overall idea is to add the element to the dictionary once visited in case of match or unmatch so that the same element is not used twice for adding up and comparison.

The code is as below:

```
def threeSum(nums):
    nums.sort()
    print(nums)
    res = []
    d = {}
    counter = 1
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        if i not in d.values() and nums[i] not in d.keys():
            start = i + 1
            end = len(nums) - 1
            while start < end:
                if (nums[i] + nums[start] + nums[end] == 0):
                    res.append([nums[i], nums[start], nums[end]])
                    print([nums[i], nums[start], nums[end]])
                    start += 1
                    end -= 1
                    i += 1
                    d[nums[i]] = i
                    d[nums[start]] = start
                    d[nums[end]] = end
                elif (nums[i] + nums[start] + nums[end] > 0):
                    end -= 1
                    d[nums[end]] = end

                i += 1
                d[nums[i]] = i
                d[start] = start
                d[end] = end
        return res
```

It works fine for below two cases when passed as an input:

```
list = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
list1 = [0, 0, 0]
```

It doesn't work for the below case:

```
list2 = [1, 2, -2, -1]
```

It returns the output as below:

```
[[-1, -1, 2]]
```

Which is incorrect. It should have returned a blank list. Where am I going wrong? I want to solve it with the help of dictionaries only and if possible in very layman's terms...

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: You need to assert that (1) all numbers in the solution are different from each other, and/or (2) each number in the given set is used only once. There may (or may not) be other issues.

Comment: Yeah I get that..It's just that there is some problem while incrementing or decrementing pointers which I am not able to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary implementation:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        length=len(nums) 
        res=[]       
        dic=dict()
        nums.sort()  #Sorted the nums Time- O(NlogN)
  
        for i in range(length):
            dic[nums[i]]=i
        #print(dic)
        i=0
        while i<length and nums[i]<=0:  #Run the while loop till i<length and nums[i] is less than or equal to zero 
            target=-(nums[i])     
            end=length
            j=i+1    # We have converted the question to 2-sum problem now just implement 2-sum.
            while j<end:
                reside=target-nums[j]
                if reside in dic and dic[reside]>j:                            
                    res.append([nums[i],nums[j],reside])
                    end=dic[reside]
                j=dic[nums[j]]+1             
           i=dic[nums[i]]+1
        return res
```